# Can active contour segment the image into different regions?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, image-segmentation

When I use the activecontour method in matlab, it seems that I can only segment the image into foreground and background, but I want to segment my MRI image into multiple regions, can I use activeconter in this case, or do I need to use other methods such as watershed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with multiple seed contours to segment multiple regions but watershed might work better depending on how much different structures are overlapping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I would like to know whether there is a function in matlab that I can use multiple seed contours directly.